# Calling jQuery function after the execution of server side onClick event of button.

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In a aspx page, If we use `onClientClick` and `onClick` for a same control, the `onClientClick` event fires first and then `onClick` will fire.

I want to do something after firing the `onClick` event. For example, for a `Button` control I've written code for its click event`(button1_click)`. After the execution of this code, I need to fire some jQuery function, is it possible. can anyone help me?

Comment: I need to call it, thats what asking

Comment: I *think* what he's saying is he wants something to run on return from the post back.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think what you are wanting to do is use some Ajax instead of a full page postback.

Comment: not like that, after execution of button click event I need to call a jQuery function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the button click event routine, use Page.RegisterStartupScript to call the JQuery function using javascript. Example in link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can have just the onClientClick="PostData"

```
<script language="javascript">
  function PostData(){
     //do something here
     __doPostBack("triggerBTN", "@@@@" + _paymentPageData);
  }
</script>
```

In you aspx page add a hidden button

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="triggerBTN" Visible="false" />
```

In the codebehind page

```
var postBackArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        if (postBackArg != null)
            if (postBackArg.StartsWith("@@@@")) {
               //do your business logic here
            }
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to call a jQuery function after a page has post back, then there are a few ways you can do this.

One of which is using the `Page.RegisterStartupScript` or `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. Both of these will output javascript onto your page after the postback.

Another way, which I tend to do, is create a public string on the page `public string _JS`, then on my .aspx page I have the following code;

```
<script>
    $(function(){ <%=_JS%> });
</script>
```

This way you can build up the `_JS` string and you know that it will fire after your DOM has loaded.

Comment: thanks Tim, I just tried Page.RegisterStartupScript, its working now